# Maximum number of push notification sent to Android device in PHP using GCM

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send multiple push notification to android devices at same time from `PHP` server to `Android devices`.

Currently we have to make array of Registered device id's then send array and message to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`(GCM)

```
$registrationIds = array("deviceid1","deviceid2" );
```

So i want to to know if i have large registered android devices than what is Maximum number of push notification sent in `PHP` using `GCM`

Currently i do not find any official source mentioning number of push notification send at a time.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Google moved from CD2M to GCM, they removed any limit in the number of recipients and also in the number of the messages sent per day.

There is, however, a limit in the length of the message (4K).

More on this latter, [take a look here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can consider to use GCM topic messaging if you don't need to keep track of registered devices

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

Comment: did u understand my question?